# what is most efficient: pass a model, or an id

Tags: laravel, model, components, render, laravel-livewire

I am thinking about the issue of speed and efficiency today, and wondering if someone can chime in on my question. The center question: is it better to pass a single id or an entire model to children livewire components.

I have a route set up:

```
Route::get(‘/single/{user}', App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Users\Main::class)->name('admin.user');
```

So [www.website.com/single/123](http://www.website.com/single/123) (123 being the unique id in a User model) will be received by the ‘Main.php ’livewire component which begins with”

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Users;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class Main extends Component
{

    public User $user;
```

So the livewire component uses the id passed in the url and injects the corresponding user model and then renders the view called main.blade.php. The mount() method actually creates the one dimensional family[] array, containing the ids for the family member model describing the users registered family members on the web site.

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.users.main',
            ['user' => $this->user, 'family' => $this->family]);
    }
```

And the main.blade.php  contains calls to two more components - the oneuser component which has a form where you can edit name, phone, address info, etc. of the registered user,  and also the familymember component, which renders once for each person in the users family where you can edit the family members names, school, age, etc. .

```
<div class="bg-white shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">

    @livewire('admin.users.header', ['user_id' => $user->id])

    <div class="grid grid-cols-12">
        <div class="col-span-6">
            @livewire('admin.users.oneuser', ['user'=>$user])
        </div>
        <div class="col-span-6">
            @foreach($family as $fm)
                @livewire('admin.users.familymember', ['family' => $fm])
            @endforeach
        </div>

    </div>
```

This got me thinking.  Notice that I only pass ids to the familymember component and I run a query in the mount() to retrieve the model for each component, but I passed the entire user model which was created in the main.php, and passed thru the main component into the oneuser component.

Is there advantage in passing the entire model thru, or would passing only the user id to main thru to oneuser component where the model could be created.

So the difference would be in the main.php, it would read:

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.users.main',
            ['user_id’ => $this->user->id, 'family' => $this->family]);
    }
```

In stead of

```
return view('livewire.admin.users.main', 
     ['user' => $this->user, 'family' => $this->family]);
```

And the user model would not be created until the mount() method of the oneuser.php livewire component.

Which is more efficient in the long run?

Thx for your consideration.

Comment: A benifit of passing an entire model rather than an identifier is you remove the requirement for a child component to perform a database request for an object you already have.

Comment: I thought about that.  And that makes sense.  And you perhaps know the answer to this, but does the original request send the entire model to the client twice?  that is, the url when it hits main.php injects the id and retrieves the model, the render() calls main.blade.php. Does the model go out to the client before the child live wire components are rendered, or does everything stay on the server until the end?

Comment: It all gets returned as part of the same response.